# In Perl script, I can open / write to/ and close a file, but I get "bad file descriptor" when I try to flock it

Tags: perl, descriptor, flock

I can OPEN the file using the file handle, but when I try to FLOCK using the same file handle I get "bad file descriptor."

```
my $file='/Library/WebServer/Documents/myFile.txt';
open(my $fh, '>', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' - $!";
    # I DO NOT GET AN ERROR FROM OPENING THE FILE

flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Could not lock '$file' - $!";
    # HERE IS WHERE I GET THE "BAD FILE DESCRIPTOR" ERROR
    # IF I COMMENT THIS LINE OUT, THE PRINT AND CLOSE COMMANDS BELOW EXECUTE NORMALLY

print $fh "hello world";
close($fh) or die "Could not write '$file' - $!";
```

It's the same file handle, so why do OPEN and PRINT work, but not FLOCK? I have tried setting the permissions for the file to 646, 666, and 777, but I always get the same results.

Thanks!

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have found your problem.

Comment: You should have gotten `Invalid argument` instead of `Bad file descriptor`.

Comment: Why are you locking a new file? If the file already exists, you are clobbering it before you get a lock, meaning you are clobbering it even if another process has a lock to it. So either you are doing something weird, or something wrong. Most likely the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Did you import the constant `LOCK_EX` per the [`flock`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#flock) documentation?

```
use Fcntl ':flock';
```

If not, `LOCK_EX` doesn't mean anything and the `flock` call will fail. Using `strict` and/or `warnings` would have identified a problem with this system call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had to change that to "use Fcntl qw(:flock);" to get it to work on my machine, but it did the trick.